# Angular component Input always return undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

One specific component of my application doesn't bind any input I pass.

My component

```js
@Component({
    selector : 'default-actions',
    templateUrl : './default.actions.template.html',
    styleUrls: [ './default.actions.style.scss' ],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class DefaultActionsComponent
{
    protected entityId;
    protected uuid = UUID.UUID();
    protected extraForms;

    @Input() protected data;
    @Input() protected structure;
    @Input() protected targetId;
    @Input() protected table;
    @Input() protected row;
    @Input() protected modal: ModalDirective;
    @Input() protected entity;
    @Input() protected entityObject: Entity;
    @Input() protected parentWrapper;
    @Input() protected foo;

    constructor(
        protected translate: TranslateService,
        protected activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        protected actionService: DefaultActionsService,
        protected router: Router,
        protected entityService: EntityService,
        protected http: HttpAuthenticationService
    ) {}

    public ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.foo);
    }
```

I use it here:

```html
<default-actions
    [table]="table['defaultListingTableComponent']"
    [row]="row"
    [foo]="'bar'"
    [modal]="modal"
    [structure]="availableColumns"
    [entityObject]="entityObject"
    [targetId]="selectedRows()">
</default-actions>
```

I added `foo` input in order to do some debugging. In console the line `console.log(this.foo);` outputs `undefined`. The same happens to all other inputs.

I believe there's something wrong with the component itself, however I'm unable to find it. Other components of my application are working.

Comment: what is the reason you defined your inputs as `protected`?

Comment: Even that should not be a problem.

Comment: This class is used as base for others. In this case I'm using `DefaultActionsComponent` itself.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz demo for this problem?

Comment: Your code works perfectly: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xzvxqr

Comment: You're right. I tried to create a stackblitz and it worked. Is there any configuration (or lack of configuration) which avoid @Input to work?

Comment: @fred00, not at least in the code we are seeing. Try removing `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` just for testing. Otherwise take the stackblitz and add more code in piece by piece to see what exactly is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

I just made a sample on Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qrgy7k

Tip:

> **Instead of directly passing string like [foo] = "'bar'", make a
>   variable in the parent component and then pass it as [foo] =
>   "yourVariable"**

Parent Component HTML:

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
<app-demo
[mydata]="datatopass"
>  
</app-demo>
```

Parent Component TS:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  datatopass = "sad";
}
```

Child Component HTML:

```
<p>
demo works!
</p>
<div>
  Data: {{ mydata }}
</div>
```

Child component TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-demo',
  templateUrl: './demo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./demo.component.css']
})
export class DemoComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() mydata;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.mydata);
  }

}
```

---

`ngOnInit()` will run when the component is initialized and at that point, it is possible that the properties you have bind do not contain data from the parent component. Try `ngOnChanges()`, `ngAfterViewInit()`

On way to tackle is to use Observable and Subject.

Comment: No luck... `ngOnChanges()` is called sometimes but in all of them `foo` is `undefined`.

Comment: Still `undefined`

Comment: That is a very strange behaviour try removing protected

Comment: I turned it into `public` but still returns `undefined`

Comment: Ok, instead of passing as "'bar'" just pass "bar" i.e remove the extra single quotes

Comment: `undefined`, but this behaviour is expected right? It understands `bar` is a variable but I never defined it.

Comment: Yes it is unexpected but don't worry, I am trying to solve it.

Comment: I just edited my answer, I think it will solve your issue now

Answer (score 1):

You should probably implement OnInit interface to make this work? Can you try?

Comment: Nothing... Still returns `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Yash ngOnInit is the correct place to do that 
But you can add ngOnChanges and add a console.log there, it might be undefined at first but whenever input changes it goes to that so you might get the value later if it is coming at any point

```
ngOnChanges() {
console.log(this.foo)
}
```

Comment: No.. It remains `undefined` :(

Comment: can you please create a stackblitz with a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Observables instead? As far as I can see, your input might still be undefined when it is passed to that child component.
@Input can be a little weird if you're not used to how it works.

Comment: I'm informing a defined string for `foo` but still returns `undefined`. As far as I understand it always be defined right?

Comment: Are you certain you have a value in foo when you pass it to your child? Perhaps you should remove the protected. There's no need for that in a component usually.

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing **AfterViewChecked** and see if you have value in **ngAfterViewChecked** like this:

```
@Component({
    selector : 'default-actions',
    templateUrl : './default.actions.template.html',
    styleUrls: [ './default.actions.style.scss' ],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class DefaultActionsComponent implements AfterViewChecked
{
    protected entityId;
    protected uuid = UUID.UUID();
    protected extraForms;

    @Input() protected data;
    @Input() protected structure;
    @Input() protected targetId;
    @Input() protected table;
    @Input() protected row;
    @Input() protected modal: ModalDirective;
    @Input() protected entity;
    @Input() protected entityObject: Entity;
    @Input() protected parentWrapper;
    @Input() protected foo;

    constructor(
        protected translate: TranslateService,
        protected activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        protected actionService: DefaultActionsService,
        protected router: Router,
        protected entityService: EntityService,
        protected http: HttpAuthenticationService
    ) {}

    public ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.foo);
    }

    ngAfterViewChecked() {
      console.log(this.foo);
    }
```

Comment: Still `undefined` =(

Answer (score 0):

The undefined output generated because you use ChangeDetectionStrategy.onPush

OnPush works by comparing references of the inputs of the component. so in your case the object reference is always the same. so the OnPush change detector did not get triggered.

you can reference to this url for more explanations: https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/

Comment: I removed this line, no luck